# Table generation with SetDelayed function

Tags: functions, interpolation, hold, assignment

I would like to understand why the following two outputs differ:

Let us define the following data set:

```
tab = Flatten[Table[{x, y, Sin[x] Cos[y]}, {x, -Pi, Pi, 0.1}, {y, -Pi, Pi, 0.1}],1];
```

and interpolate it:

```
finterpol = Interpolation[tab];
```

Now, we define

```
f[x0_] := ND[finterpol[x, 0.3], x, x0];
```

with [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html). Calling   `f[2]` returns  `-0.397576` as expected. However:

```
Table[f[x], {x, 0, 2, 0.2}]
```

returns only zeros. If one defines the function `f` without the delay,

```
f[x0_] = ND[finterpol[x, 0.3], x, x0];
```

one gets the correct output.

Comment: I suspect a conflict between the `x` variable you use in the `Table`, and the one in the definition of `f`. For instance, `Table[f[i], {i, 0, 2, 0.2}]` works just fine with the delayed definition.

Comment: When `f` is defined with `SetDelayed`, the right-hand side contains `x` and is recomputed for each `x0`, however `Table` localizes `x`: for example, consider `Block[{x = 0}, f[2]]`. In the second definition, `ND` is evaluated once and it doesn't matter if `x` has a value later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is best to approach these kinds of problems with pure functions, which minimizes nasty surprises from variable scoping issues. Let's see how well this idea works out when applied to your problem.

Generate test data.

```
With[{u = Range[-180., 180., 6.] Degree},
  data =
    With[{x = #[[1]], y = #[[2]]}, {x, y, Sin[x] Cos[ y]}] & /@ 
      Flatten[Outer[List, u, u], 1]];
```

Visualize the test data.

```
 ListPlot3D[data]
```

[image: dataplot]

Make the interpolating function.

```
f = Interpolation[data];
```

Visualize the interpolating function.

```
Block[{x, y}, 
  With[{domain = 
          Sequence @@ MapThread[Flatten@List[#1, #2] &, {{x, y}, f["Domain"]}]},
   Plot3D[f[x, y], domain]]]
```

[image: funcplot]

Make an interpolating function for the 1st derivative with respect to the 1st argument. This will be a pure function.

```
Block[{x, y}, dfx = Head @ D[f[x, y], x]]
```

[image: derivativefunc]

Now define the special function the evaluates the 1st derivative with respect to the 1st argument with the 2nd argument held at `.3`.

```
specialDF[x0_] = dfx[x0, .3];
```

Use `specialDF` to show a series of tangents to the data surface in the `x+` direction and lying the plane `y == 0.3`.

```
With[{arrowData = 
  With[{n = 6, min = dfx["Domain"][[1, 1]], max = dfx["Domain"][[1, 2]]}, 
    Table[{{x, .3, f[x, .3]}, specialDF[x]}, {x, min, max, (max - min)/(n - 1)}]]},
    Show[
      ListPlot3D[data,
        PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5],
        PlotTheme -> "NoAxes"], 
      Graphics3D[{
        Red, Arrow[Tube[{#[[1]], #[[1]] + {1., 0., #[[2]]}}, .05]] & /@ arrowData}],
      PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: tangents]